# OptaPlanner : FilterClass configuration in ValueSelector

Tags: optaplanner, drools-planner

I am using OptaPlanner 6.1.0.Final. When I try to use FilterClass in ValueSelector configuration, I got this exception:

**Caused by**: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$UnknownFieldException: No such field org.optaplanner.core.config.heuristic.selector.value.ValueSelectorConfig.filterClass

Acording to the OptaPlanner docs (in 7.2.4. Filtered selection), FilterClass should also work on ValueSelector.

```
...apply it on a lower levels, such as a filterClass on the entitySelector or valueSelector:

 <changeMoveSelector>
  <entitySelector>
    <filterClass>...EntityFilter</filterClass>
  </entitySelector>
</changeMoveSelector>
```

Is this a bug on the Planner? Or any other way to have Filtering class for Planning Variables?
Appreciated for your time and suggestion in advance.

Below is my configuration:

```
<changeMoveSelector>
                <entitySelector mimicSelectorRef="placerEntitySelector">
                </entitySelector>
                <valueSelector>
                    <variableName>room</variableName>
                    <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
                    <selectionOrder>SORTED</selectionOrder>
      <filterClass>..SelectionFilter</filterClass>
                    </valueSelector>
            </changeMoveSelector>
```

Comment: Take a look at the class `EntitySelectorConfig.java`: XStream converts your piece of XML into an instance of that class - and apparently fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`<valueSelector>` does not support filters yet** (see TODO `ValueSelectorConfig.java`). It's debatable whether that's useful: if you have a good use case, do share.

Note that the surrounding `<moveSelector>` does support filtering. In that case, you're filtering moves (a `ChangeMove` in this case), instead of values - so there's more info, namely both the entity and the value, instead of just the value.

Comment: I have a hard rule for example as in NQueen, some particular queens can move only to even number rows. To make that rule as build-in hard constraint, I need to have something like filtered variables or possible move list for that queen. This is indeed to increase performance** of every solving step as I have more than 400 hard constraints. Appreciated any suggestions. Thanks.